# Set of images stacked with offset increase for each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of images, which I'd like to stack, one on top of each other, then offset each image by 30px top and left.

```
<ul>
   <li><img src="#"></li>
   <li><img src="#"></li>
   <li><img src="#"></li>
   <li><img src="#"></li>
   <li><img src="#"></li>
</ul>
```

I found a jsFiddle of a similar effect (http://jsfiddle.net/BrAbs/1/) but require the left position to be offset and increase for each image too (0px, 30px, 60px, 90px) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('li').each(function (i) {
    $(this).css({
        left: 30 * i
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BrAbs/15/)

Requires `position:relative` on the elements which you're setting the `left` CSS property to.

---

As requested, you can also use `absolute`ly positioning relative to an `relative`ly positioned ancestor if you need the stack effect without setting `height` on the `li`s:

```
.ulClass {
    position: relative; /*resets the absolute positioning of descendant li(s)*/
}
.ulClass li {
    position: absolute; /*absolute positioning relatively to ancestor .ulClass*/
}
```

Then the updated JS adding a `top` offset:

```
$('li').each(function (i) {
    $(this).css({
        top: 30 * i,
        left: 30 * i
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BrAbs/17/)

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there anyway to stack the images without applying a height to the li? So they are absolutely positioned on top then offset using your code both top and left?

Comment: @rdck, Yes set the container to `relative` and absolutely position the `li`s. Sec while I update the fiddle